# why most verilog codes work in posedge clock?

Tags: verilog

Why in most verilog codes, it works only on posedge clock?

If we can make it work as well in negedge clock, then throughput would be higher.
We could lengthen the clock cycle and make use of both positive and negative clock.

My professor said something about the features of inverter that it can only have strength either in positive clock and negative side and also mentioned something about H tree..which I didn't understand what that is..

Is there anyone who can explain me about this?

Thanks

Comment: Because Verilog is most commonly used to model the behaviour of logic circuits, and that's how most logic devices work (edge-triggered flip-flops).

Comment: You *can* write Verilog code that is sensitive to the negative edge of the clock.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39709/using-both-edges-of-a-clock

Answer (score 0):

Because many Verilog designs are targeted for FPGAs, and FPGA designs behave better (= timing analysis is easier so it's also easier to spot early timing errors and try to fix them during the P&R phase) if events are triggered using only one edge of the clock.

But the language doesn't prevent you from using more than one edge of the same or different clock sources. It will work nicely on simulation, but will unlikely be valid for FPGA synthesis.